# Calculating the absolute margin of error of a circuit

Tags: microcontroller, adc, dac, error

I need to calculate the absolute margin of error of a measuring circuit that is composed of a DAC and an ADC. The DAC (MCP4725) has a margin of error of +-2 LSB, and the ADC (ATMEGA328P) has a margin of error of +-2 LSB. Keep in mind that the resolution of the DAC is 12-bit, and the ADC is 10-bit.

I looked and I found about "error propagation", which seems to be the most viable solution to this (assuming that the error for each IC is the margin of error divided by the resolution).

Thanks!

Comment: Absolute margin of error is used to define the half spectrum of values for a given %confidence requirement in a measurement system. This includes the signal/noise ratio, signal to resolution ratio, THD , Vref error, temperature range, schematic/layout/cabling flaws, clock speed, CM and DM noise, oversampling rate, averaging, code flaws.  But some factors can be improved with calibration and design improvements. It takes 4x as long with averages to gain 1 bit of accuracy if noise appears random. SNR must be >=62dB otherwise.

Comment: Accuracy specs always assume zero design flaws in software, hardware, layout, wiring , EMI rejection, supply drift and from lack of experience. The same is true for MTBF. It excludes application design flaws.

Comment: Do you plan on using ADC quiet mode and disable Analog comparator?

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 I didn't find anything about the "ADC Quiet Mode", but I did disable the Analog comparator.

Comment: Do you plan on using Nyquist band stop filter? Enter ADC Noise Reduction mode (or Idle mode). The ADC will start a conversion
once the CPU has been halted If no other interrupts occur before the ADC conversion completes, the ADC interrupt will wake up the CPU and execute the ADC Conversion Complete interrupt routine.

Comment: Although Andy describes the ideal conversion it does not answer the worst case. Within  the IC there are noise sources that contribute an unknown quantity of error when digital clocks or channels are running other than the ADC.

Comment: Alright, thanks Tony! I will implement such changes to my code. Again, thanks!

Comment: Conversion rate also affects accuracy. I suggest you implement a closed loop test with DAC and ADC and use the LC filter with a bandgap reference supply.  Normally the designer asks for a spec rather than being asked how good or bad is it.

Answer (score 2):

Convert ADC error counts (LSbs) to real numbers (voltages) and then add the equivalent DAC error voltages to the ADC error voltages. However, you also need to take account of the following for each and don't ignore any.

- integral non linearity error
- differential non linearity
- gain span error
- zero offset error
- reference voltage error

All the above errors can be additive so, if you want worst case total errors, you must sum them for both parts. You should also consider temperature variations from ambient and how much this makes things worse. For instance, the voltage reference is likely affected most and this problem can be very significant.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! In order to take those errors you mentioned into account, how can I change the errors to voltage? Do I multiply the reference voltage by the quotient of the error by the resolution? (Vref * (error/resolution))

Comment: If you have a 10 bit device, the full scale is 1023 bits and, if the full nominal input voltage span of the device is (say) 10.23 volts then 1 LSb equals 10 mV. You can use the reference voltage but the devil is in the detail and it isn't always simply related to the full input span.

Comment: Uncertainty-of-measurement is an important subject to learn.  You can either use a lot of statistical measurements of accurate voltages or the RMS of the calculated errors for simple applications to calculate the UOM (the uncertainty.)

Comment: @user1831847 Or you can use worst case errors as the question asks.

Comment: @Andyaka In statistics the worst case error is in the tail of the normal distribution and that is infinity ($$\pm \infty$$ :-)

Comment: Don't try and get clever with me. You made a statement without considering the question and this might give lesser mortals a suspicion that my answer was somehow flawed. Yes, when it comes to analysing the rms error what you say is valid but, in measurement of dc applications absolute error is what my customers are interested in .

Comment: There are noise sources within the CPU that need to be disabled to achieve the 2 bit absolute accuracy.

Comment: even using 3MHz ADC clock has a 3 bit error in spec and that is just typical and there are many more sources of system measurement error than in your excellent answer.